# Dart library waterfall principle like async from caolan

Tags: dart, dart-async

Earlier, i was a javascript programmer and i use the library async from caolan to prevent callback hell [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async).

In these days i moved to dart and the async style is pretty much the same like in javascript. I really like async.waterfall function, that I can execute functions with callback in order.

How can I do that in dart? They have a similar library in dart available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply chain the results of Futures together:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
 first()
  .then(second)
  .then(third)
  .then(fourth);
}

Future<String> first() {
  return new Future.sync(() => "first");
}

Future<int> second(String arg ) {
  return new Future.sync(() => 2);
}

Future<List<int>> third(int arg) {
  return new Future.sync(() => [1, 2, 3]);
}

Future<String> fourth(List<int> arg ) {
  return new Future.sync(() => "Final result is: $arg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for `Future`

- https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/
- [https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart%3aasync)
- [https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async.Future](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart%3aasync.Future)

Comment: Yes, i know, but how can i use in waterfall style?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to build such a functionality. I guess the harder part is how to cope with varying number of arguments. If you would add a concrete example what you want to do with it, it would be easier. Currently I'm not convinced that this has any advantage.